# DNS Not Update from Last 7days

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I Update my DNS in Network solution domain providers but my nameserver not updated yet from last 7days i checked dns many time but not update
my website still not pointing hosting [www.itcrew.in](http://www.itcrew.in)

Answer (score 3):

Whois search shows that your registrar is Godaddy. A check of your current name server `nslookup -type=soa itcrew.in` responds:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
itcrew.in
        primary name server = cameron.ns.cloudflare.com
        responsible mail addr = dns.cloudflare.com
        serial  = 2332279957
        refresh = 10000 (2 hours 46 mins 40 secs)
        retry   = 2400 (40 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 1800 (30 mins)
```

Implication being that it's Cloudflare that is authoritative, so until you change the authoritative DNS for your domain, you can change anything in Network Solutions and it will have no effect. The authoritative DNS for your domain will be a thing you set in the GoDaddy control panel, and if you want to have Network Solutions handle your DNS, check there first for the name servers they want you to use, then tell GoDaddy to use them.